# Regular expression getting html between two comments

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get a snippet of HTML between to comments.

I will need to parse the HTML between the start/end later.

I am actually reading from an html file but for test purposes I mocked the following up:

```
        string emailFeedTxtStart = "<!--FEED FOR RECEIPT GOES HERE-->";
        string emailFeedTxtEnd = "<!--FEED FOR RECEIPT ENDS HERE-->";

        string html =
            emailFeedTxtStart + Environment.NewLine +
            @"<td align=""center"">" + Environment.NewLine +
            @"<table style=""table-layout:fixed;width:380px"" border=""0"" cellspacing=""0""             cellpadding=""0"">" + Environment.NewLine +
            "<tbody>" + Environment.NewLine +
            "<tr>" + Environment.NewLine +
            "<td>" + Environment.NewLine +
            "</td>" + Environment.NewLine +
            "</tr>" + Environment.NewLine +
            "</tbody>" + Environment.NewLine +
            "</table>" + Environment.NewLine +
            "</td>"  + Environment.NewLine +
            emailFeedTxtEnd; 

        string patternstart = Regex.Escape(emailFeedTxtStart);
        string patternend = Regex.Escape(emailFeedTxtEnd);
        string regexexpr = patternstart + @"(.*?)" + patternend;
        //string regexexpr = @"(?<=" + patternstart + ")(.*?)(?=" + patternend + ")";

        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(@html, @regexexpr);
```

matches returned is 0.

(note there is a lot more HTML between the ).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest experimenting using a tool like RegexHero: http://regexhero.net/

Comment: Why do you need regex? Why not just either get the indexes of the literal strings using `IndexOf` and/or just splitting the string using your constants?

Comment: I don't, I am also trying html agility pack... But wanted to keep the question specific to one method. There are many possible ways to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you going to parse the HTML with after? Because there's probably a way you can just do away with actually manipulating the HTML string beforehand. Here's a solution anyway:

```
    string afterFirst = html.Substring(Regex.Match(html, emailFeedTxtStart).Index + emailFeedTxtStart.Length);
    string between = afterFirst.Substring(0, Regex.Match(afterFirst, emailFeedTxtEnd).Index);
```

Comment: I will check this out in the morning. Thx